# Migrating odd subversion layout to git with history

Tags: svn, git, version-control, git-svn

I have a subversion repo with an odd layout:

trunk

```
Project1

Project2
```

tags

```
Project1-0.2.4

Project2-1.9.0
```

branches

```
Project1-crazyidea
```

I know, I know, this was stupid.  I should have had a trunk, tags, and branches directory underneath each Project.  However, is there anyway to convert this to git (for a particular project) with history?

Most of the git-svn tutorials assume the standard layout, and do not cover this particular situation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you intend to abandon the SVN repository once it has been converted to Git, then you should consider splitting the SVN repo prior to the conversion.

[`svndumpfilter`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svndumpfilter.html) can be used to split the two (or more) repositories into independent repos (with their complete history).  Once this is complete, [`git svn`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) can be used to import them.

Comment: svndumpfilter doesn't work well on multi-project repositories where directories and files have been moved / copied many time throughout the history of the repository.   svndumpsanitizer works better in this case.  See http://miria.linuxmaniac.net/svndumpsanitizer/